# fixing Missing values : ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape

Tags: python

Please I need help. am trying to fix the missing data but am getting an error message.

```
dataset_train = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
dataset_test = pd.read_csv("test_data.csv")

X_train = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:11].values

y_train = dataset_train.iloc[:, 13].values
X_test = dataset_test.iloc[:, 1:11].values
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
missingvalues = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="mean", verbose=0)
missingvalues_train = missingvalues.fit(X_train[:,[7, 9]])
X_train[:,1:11] =np.array(missingvalues_train.transform(X_train[:,[7,9]]))
```

This is the error message

```
X_train[:,1:11] =np.array(missingvalues_train.transform(X_train[:,[7,9]]))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-15-b81359273b14>", line 1, in <module>
    X_train[:,1:11] =np.array(missingvalues_train.transform(X_train[:,[7,9]]))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7160,2) into shape (7160,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only two columns or rows to a DataFrame object that is expecting nine rows or columns. You would have to include more indices in list you are passing to the X_train DataFrame.